# Enable UIScrollView scrolling for particular CGPoint on UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I want to enable scrolling of UIScrollView only when i swipe from screen boundaries. I am using swipe gesture recognizer.

here is my code

```
-(void)swipeHandlerLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRecognizer
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    point =  [swipeRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    if(swipeRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        if (point.x > screenWidth - 10)
        {
            NSLog(@"Swipped Left");
            _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            _scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        }
    }

}

-(void)swipeHandlerRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRecognizer
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    point =  [swipeRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    if(swipeRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        if (point.x < 10)
        {
            NSLog(@"Swipped Right");
            _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            _scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        }
    }    
}
```

Problem with above code is it works until scrollview is not enabled,but once it is enabled this methods are not getting called and i think the reason for that is as i've added scrollview inside of my UIView.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView already has UIGestureRecognizer inside of it. 
I think you would need to connect your code to those gestureRecognizers. You can access them by `myScrollView.panGestureRecognizer` and `myScrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you,but could you please demonstrate your idea with some small demo code..

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollview catches your touch before your swipe view, and I suppose the swipe gesture recognizer is on the superview of the scroll view.

You must create a dependency by calling `requireGestureRecognizerToFail(_:)`
 on your scrollView pan gesture recognizer, and passing your swipe gesture.